# JSON.NET Deserializing recursive abstract class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My data structure looks like this:

```
public abstract class Argument
{
}

public class StringArgument : Argument
{
    public string Test { get; }

    public StringArgument(string test)
    {
        Test = test;
    }
}

public class SetArgument : Argument
{
    public HashSet<Argument> Args { get; }

    public SetArgument(HashSet<Argument> args)
    {
        Args = args;
    }
}
```

I need to serialize and deserialize instances of the Argument class. After some research I found out I needed to use a custom JsonConverter for the type Argument. But the problem is: The CanConvert method won't be called for nested properties.

I know I can add some atrributes, but I don't want to do that (for more reasons). I found out I probably needed to override the IContractResolver somehow. So I tried something like this:

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private static readonly ArgumentConverter Converter = new ArgumentConverter();

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

        contract.Converter = Converter;

        return contract;
    }
}
```

But again, the CreateContract method doesn't get called for the interior arguments.

What can I do please?

Comment: Are you bound to json.net? How shall the target JSON look like(a more "copy paste"-able Version of you code would be nice, e.g. a simple example structure)?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the code for your `ArgumentConverter` class as well as some sample JSON that you are trying to deserialize?  This will help greatly in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: A [mcve] would greatly help us to help you.  See [ask].